# Array concatenation of index in php

Tags: php

i have following array format in php:

```
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => RSJ Pole 116 x100 ,11 Mtr
            [1] => RSJ Pole 116 x100 ,10 Mtr
            [2] => RSJ Pole 116 x 100, 9 Mtr
            [3] => RSJ Pole 116 x 100, 8 Mtr
            [4] => Line Length in Kms
            [5] => RSJ 125x70, 9 m long
            [6] => PSC Pole 9 Mtr
            [7] => PSC Pole 8 Mtr
            [8] => Conductor ACSR Dog 0.1
            [9] => Conductor ACSR Rabbit 55 Sq.mm
            [10] => Conductor ACSR Raccon 80 Sq.mm
            [11] => Conductor Weisel 34 Sq.mm
            [12] => Conductor Ant
            [13] => Conductor Gnat
            [14] => New DTC 100 KVA
            [15] => New DTC 63 KVA
            [16] => BPL Connection
            [17] => SDT
        )

    [scope] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1172
            [1] => 6637
            [2] => 854
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 653.71
            [5] => 558.9
            [6] => 5864
            [7] => 820
            [8] => 745385
            [9] => 1188772.2
            [10] => 327600
            [11] => 18900
            [12] => 232015.9
            [13] => 70634.3
            [14] => 344
            [15] => 54
            [16] => 13632
            [17] => 37
        )

    [till] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 5
            [7] => 5
            [8] => 2
            [9] => 5
            [10] => 5
            [11] => 5
            [12] => 5
            [13] => 5
            [14] => 5
            [15] => 5
            [16] => 5
            [17] => 2
        )

    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] =>  7
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
        )

    [submit] => submit
)
```

i want to concatenate with "_" operator before submitting or while inserting into database field for eg. 1172_3_4

Comment: `$arr = []; for($i=0;$i<18;$i++)$arr[] = implode("_", array_column($main_array, $i)); var_dump($arr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `array_map` the 3 arrays

```
$arr = .... //Your array here

$results = array_map(function($s, $t, $v) {
    return $s . "_" . $t . "_" . $v;
}, $arr['scope'], $arr['till'], $arr['value']);

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $results );
echo "</pre>";
```

`$results` will have the value:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1172_3_4
    [1] => 6637_4_7
    [2] => 854_4_1
    [3] => 4_6_2
    [4] => 653.71_5_
    [5] => 558.9_5_
    [6] => 5864_5_
    [7] => 820_5_
    [8] => 745385_2_
    [9] => 1188772.2_5_
    [10] => 327600_5_
    [11] => 18900_5_
    [12] => 232015.9_5_
    [13] => 70634.3_5_
    [14] => 344_5_
    [15] => 54_5_
    [16] => 13632_5_
    [17] => 37_2_
)
```

Doc: [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the loop at main array and increment in $i then concatenate $array_variable['scope'][$i].'_'.$array_variable['till'][$i].'_'.$array_variable['value'][$i].